# Most interesting questions/answers

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This question is for the purposes of [promoting](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/the-best-posts-of-skeptics) Islam.SE. Please nominate others' contributions as answers to this question.

### Rules

- Post a link to a good question from Islam.SE that has a great answer(s).
- Provide a short description on why you think the question should be nominated.
- Please nominate and upvote only the best of the best.

Remember, these nominations should represent the *best* of what Islam.SE has to offer, and should draw in experts. If a question needs some perfecting... perfect it! Correct the grammar, remove the inaccuracies, and improve the clarity.

Happy nominating!

Comment: Related: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/124/128

Comment: Hmmmm... how does this help promotion?

Comment: @Dynamic These top questions can be tweeted, Reddited, Google+'ed, /.'ed ...well, not /.'ed but yeah.

Comment: We don't need to gather them here though... Idk, we'll see how it works.

Comment: @Dynamic This has been done on [Meta.Skeptics.SE](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/442/the-best-posts-of-skeptics) before.

Comment: Looks like they had good results. In that case, fire away :-).