# Best Questions of this site

Tags: discussion, support

Inspired from a post in [christianitySE](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4549/can-questions-be-listed-by-number-of-times-viewed)...
thought even IslamSE should have a list of its top questions in the decreasing order of number of views.

[Most Views](https://data.stackexchange.com/islam/query/295002/questions-in-decreasing-order-of-views) (you can change the number by editing it as u like)

**Another tour for an enthusiast to capture contemporary issues based on their popularity.** Apart from [top votes](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes).

Still want some insights, you can cover as many possible from this [list of favorite queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/islam/queries).

Or you can peek into the most [controversial questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/islam/query/466/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site) which have been asked.

Or the other way around, you can find the creamy posts/answers from [top answerers in this site](https://data.stackexchange.com/islam/query/952/top-500-answerers-on-the-site).

The above things are for you to help explore the interesting things in this site. But remember the whole [site](https://islam.stackexchange.com/) is interesting.

Have fun!

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most interesting questions/answers](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/most-interesting-questions-answers)

Answer (score 1):

A hidden feature on StackExchange sites is the [greatest hits](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits) which lists the top 1000 questions according to the following:

> Questions that got a large amount of views or a large amount of feedback.
>
> The current algorithm divides the number of page views with the total amount of question and answer feedback received (adding a bonus for high view counts), excluding questions with less views than the median :- 297.

The top 5 are:

1. [In Islam, are there limits on sex between a married couple?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1355/17163)
2. [How many Sunnat rakats are there in Jumma prayer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8641/17163)
3. [When does the time for fajr prayer end?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10000/17163)
4. [Why is homosexuality a sin if Allah made me this way?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5686/17163)
5. [Is it haram to visualize having sex?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12901/17163)